# How can I see a list of modified files in the fuzzy finder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working on a project, git keeps track of files that have changed i.e. the list of files you get when running `git status`. I'd like to be able to use the fuzzy finder (<kbd>⌘/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) to search through only those files.

Is there a way to open the fuzzy finder with only those files to select from?